# Endpoints behavior of binomial series

Tags: calculus, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

The binomial series is known a ∑(1+x)^k 
The last step for me to understand this series is when x equals to either 1 or -1. 
Basically, I could compute that k must be greater than -1 to converge when x = -1 or 1. 
I just don't understand what the internet and book propose--the series converges at 1 if  -1 < k < 0 and at both endpoints if  k > 0.
I could only come up with -1 < k. I can't even find the bit of k < 0.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, shd be a series rather than a sequence

Answer (score 0):

1 + a.sum(k=0,n) a$^k$ = sum(k=0,n) a$^k$ + a$^{n+1}$
sum(k=0,n) a$^k$ = (1 - a$^{n+1}$)/(1 - a)
Sum converges when |a| < 1.
Your series converges when |1 + x| < 1
which is equivalent to -1 < 1 + x < 1.

In the last part are you confusing k with x?
I have understood you're talking about a geometric series.
If that is wrong, then write explicitly what the binomial series is.

Comment: Sorry but i am referring to the converging point when x = 1 and x = -1

Comment: It still remains a mystery what binomial series you are considering.  Give an explicitc fo

Comment: It remains a mystery what the series you are considering.  Give a clear, full and explicit description of the series. @AndesLam